# SslSocketConnector - Cannot assign requested address after migrationg to compute engine

Tags: java, https, google-compute-engine

In my app I am using:

```
    SslSocketConnector connector = new SslSocketConnector();
    connector.setKeystore(certificatePath);
    connector.setPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setKeyPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setTruststore(certificatePath);
    connector.setTrustPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setPort(8805);
    connector.setHost(www.mydomain.com);
```

(to receive google token to use google calendar API) this used to work well on my server, but receantly I migrated to **compute engine** and since then I started to get: **java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)**.
DNS record for **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** have public IP of compute engine instance.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can use **[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)** for **SetHost()** because that hostname does not resolve to a network interface.

You should use the system's hostname or private IP address of the interface to bind to or set it to null for all interfaces. The preferred method is all interfaces (null).

Tip: Even though your DNS server points to the public IP address of your instance, the public IP address is not bound to your instance. The public IP is bound to a special one-to-one NAT. Your instance only knows about the private IP addresses bound to the network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

For the [documentation](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/fixing-javanetbindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-JVMbind.html#axzz73v87Pr3Z) you can see the following.

```
Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.
```

The error for this issue is the second condition related to the local address, so you need to modify this. In Linux systems you need to modify /etc/hosts and for Windows systems this could be found in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

You need to correct or add the local host to these files to correct it.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```